# Are my session settings secure enough?

Tags: php, csrf, session-management, session-fixation

I'm developing a file hosting and sharing web application.

Are the following PHP session settings secure enough?

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); 
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool'); //is whirlpool that necessary?
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);

session_name('sid');

session_start();

if (!isset($_COOKIE['sid'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = CryptoCharGen::alnum(); //20 chars
}
```

**To add on to the security:**

- Tying a cryptographically strong CSRF token  to the user
  session for form validation.
- Regenerating a new session ID upon logging in and out and destroying the old session.
- Regenerating a new CSRF token upon successful submission of *any* form.

I've read to rename the default PHP session name, so I named it `sid` instead. Is that good enough?

Should I generate the session id with my own generator? (CryptoCharGen)

Should I be concerned about how I name my session variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also add `session.entropy_length = 512` and `session.use_trans_sid = 0`.

Also do not forget to:

1. use https
2. regenerate [session id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) if you change users permissions.
3. do sessions time out. Time depends on your app.

It has nothing to do with security, but why not to change `session.hash_bits_per_character` to 6. The bigger the number, the shorter the string sent from and to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few extra steps which can make session secure.

1. Limit the session validity for accepted short time
2. Always transmit session ids on SSL/TLS
3. Never send session ids on URLs (Use post
   method)
4. Make Strong CSRF tokens and Make sure CSRF tokens are validated.

You can find more on

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Management